# Argument type 'System.Type' is not assignable to parameter type 'bool'

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, serialization

When searching through SO for a way of deserializing XML the following keeps popping up:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
```

but when I paste it into my code, I get the lovely red line under typeof(MyClass) stating that:

```
Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'bool'
Argument type 'System.Type' is not assignable to parameter type 'bool'
```

Well that's great.. Since all you guys manage to make it work. MyClass looks like this btw:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Blabla[] Bla {get; set;}
    public SomethingElse[] Som {get; set;}
}
```

Anyone who can give me a hint about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Right click on XmlSerializer and select Go to definition. I'm betting that's not the XmlSerializer you think it is.

Comment: How come you dont have the `[Serializable()]` above your class? And what is `Blabla[]` and `SomethingElse[]`?

Comment: Because he doesn't need that for the xml serializer?

Comment: holy.... I feel pretty dumb right now... thanks...

Comment: @Will is right. I was using the wrong XmlSerializer...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ [Serializable()] is redundant when using XmlSerializer

Comment: Add an answer below with details and close this out. I'm interested in exactly *what* XmlSerializer you're using here. (Yes, adding your own answer is an acceptable way of handling this)

Comment: Why has someone downvoted this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** As Will commented, the XmlSerializer wasn't the one that I thought it was. 
I was using the one from the ServiceStack namespace instead of the System.Xml.Serialization - which is the correct one.

Pressing F12 (using ReSharper) on the class will also indicate this.